# RTCMultiConnection iOS 11 safari audio/video stream issue

Tags: ios, video, safari, streaming, rtcmulticonnection

I'm using the RTCMulticonnection library for a webrtc video streaming platform. It functions pretty much like this: There's a list of users, each with a profile page that has a chat button. Upon clicking this chat button, the caller is taken into a chat room page (a new browser tab) where he issues a `connection.open()` to create the room.

Afterwards a chat request is send through the node server to the callee, which gets a confirmation popup. If he accepts he is taken in the chat room page (a new tab) where a `connection.join(roomId)` is called.

My problem is that on ipad/iphone both the audio AND video stream are added only on the first call, either if you are a caller or a callee. If you afterwards want to call someone else on the ipad only the audio stream is added to the chat view, but from the remote side you get the video stream just fine.

Is there a flag that gets set up somewhere, somehow that I'm missing?

Also there's some cases that causes iOS devices to freeze up pretty bad so that they need a hard reboot, but I haven't pinned down the culprit.

On desktops and android devices the flow seems to work fine... so far.

Comment: Upon further investigation: it seems that after opening the new tab and connecting only with the microphone, if i hit refresh and a new socket id is attached, the video stream goes through just fine, but i still don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you using Angular 2+ or zone.js?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WebKit:

- [Safari on iOS11 Freezes when viewing a cropped remote video](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176439)
- [Frequent situations where iOS device locks up, requiring a hard reboot when consuming webrtc streams on IOS](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175014)

It's solved since iOS 11.2.